# Can PouchDB sync with other database solutions such as Percona

Tags: percona, pouchdb

I really dig the concept behind PouchDB and would be very interested in learning if it would be possible to sync it with a server database solution such as Percona.

http://www.percona.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, but you could build a kind of proxy that implements the Couchdb Replication Interface and transforms the commands to a mysql client and vice-versa.

PouchDb is built to replicate to any backend database that supports the couchdb replication api.